# python codition sum by index

Tags: python, sum, conditional-statements

I want to make a new column by condition sum.

But I don't know how to make it in this status:

| index | Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume | Change | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-12-14 | 2205 | 2205 | 2150 | 2185 | 180466 | -0.011312 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-12-15 | 2195 | 2195 | 2155 | 2185 | 139561 | 0.000000 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-12-16 | 2195 | 2430 | 2180 | 2370 | 2909662 | 0.084668 | 1 |
| 3 | 2020-12-17 | 2425 | 2425 | 2290 | 2330 | 587914 | -0.016878 | 0 |
| 4 | 2020-12-18 | 2335 | 2355 | 2225 | 2295 | 374375 | -0.015021 | 0 |
| 5 | 2020-12-21 | 2250 | 2350 | 2250 | 2305 | 264192 | 0.004357 | 0 |
| 6 | 2020-12-22 | 2330 | 2345 | 2245 | 2255 | 327715 | -0.021692 | 0 |
| 7 | 2020-12-23 | 2260 | 2300 | 2185 | 2220 | 194277 | -0.015521 | 0 |
| 8 | 2020-12-24 | 2220 | 2235 | 2155 | 2165 | 208300 | -0.024775 | 0 |
| 9 | 2020-12-28 | 2170 | 2180 | 2110 | 2120 | 201740 | -0.020785 | 0 |

```
last = len(df)

df['Gap_up_cnt_3d'] = [df.loc[last-j-3:last-j-1,"Close"].sum() if t< 19 else t in list(df.index.values)> ]
```

I want:

```
index(9)["Gap_up_cnt_df'] = sum(index(9).Close ,index(8).Close, index(7).Close) 

index(8)["Gap_up_cnt_df'] = sum(index(8).Close ,index(7).Close, index(6).Close)
```

NB: This is not an exact expression, just to convey meaning

Comment: What do you wish to obtain from this condition `if t< 19 else t in list(df.index.values)>`?

Comment: That is just try code , ignore that. i want df['Gap_up_cnt_df'][9] = sum(index(9).Close ,index(8).Close, index(7).Close)

Comment: So, basically you need a column which adds the `Close` values from the three rows preceeding a row?

Comment: I want show your example code